# CodeKit3 Bash script to uglify

Tags: bash, codekit

The end goal of this long winded post is to Uglify & Mangle the output file (after everything else is prepended) using a CodeKit Hook, so that once the files are combined to then run the Uglify from the Hook so the "eof" error is bypassed.

Some examples I have tried using in the Bash script hook area of CodeKit's UI. Also more details posted below of how my solution is structured in CodeKit.

Thanks for reading.

```
# Outputs a copy of "common.js" file with new name, but does not uglify or mangle
$uglify $CK_OUTPUT_PATH \
         -o $CK_PROJECT_ROOT/js/common.min.js -c –m

# Same thing, outputs only a copy with new name
$CK_OUTPUT_PATH uglifyjs --compress --mangle --output $CK_PROJECT_ROOT/js/common.min.js
```

Using CodeKit3 I have a file that has several prepends of other files that is something like below.

```js
// @codekit-prepend "rules.js"
// @codekit-prepend "domStart.js"

    // @codekit-prepend "mainStructure.js"
    // @codekit-prepend "pages.js"
    // @codekit-prepend "grids.js"
    // @codekit-prepend "modals.js"
    // @codekit-prepend "thirdParty.js"
    // @codekit-prepend "s508.js"

// @codekit-prepend "domEnd.js"
```

The options for CodeKit are very easy to use, but I have a problem. Because many of the files I prepend require DOM ready, I have created two files, one "domStart.js", and "domEnd.js" and they are exactly what they sound like.

"domStart.js" contains...

```js
$(function(){
```

"domEnd.js" contains...

```js
});//end ready
```

Thusly everything in the middle is now wrapped in a single `$(function(){ *prepended files* });//end ready` statement.

The problem is when i goto compress, uglify, or mangle the files through CodeKits UI I get the following error output in the console of CodeKit. I know that it is because the "domStart.js" files contains an opening "{" with no closure, thus the end of file error.

```
UglifyJS: Minification failed:

Parse error at /Users/colemmic/dev/roomstogo-store/roomstogo-web/src/main/webapp/static/js/common/domStart.js:1,13
$(function(){
             ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: eof (undefined)
    at JS_Parse_Error.get (eval at <anonymous> (/Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:27:1), <anonymous>:86:23)
    at /Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs:384:39
    at time_it (/Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs:620:15)
    at /Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs:345:9
    at tryToString (fs.js:455:3)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:442:12)
```

Comment: FYI, "snippet" support in StackOverflow is specifically for JavaScript that can be run in a browser. Use the `{}` button to syntax-highlight other languages without the "Run code snippet" button &c.

Answer (score 1):

After many hours of additional research into this I have devised a solution that works.

Because CodeKit3 is slight different the full path to uglify must be defined.

```
/Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs $CK_OUTPUT_PATH \
         -p -c -m -o $CK_PROJECT_ROOT/js/common.min.js
```

So the above statements were not far off, but because the app houses all the frameworks within it just needs to have them defined before they can run.